# Problem with String& argument of a function

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm, string, functions

I am trying to send SMSs using a GSM module with Arduino Mega. I have followed a tutorial and downloaded the SIM908IDE100 library. I am using the function

`SendSMS(String&, const char [27]);`.

It works fine when I type:

`sms.SendSMS("1234567890","Text message");`

where "1234567890" is the telephone number I want to send the SMS to and "Text message" is the text of the SMS.

If I instead try to pass to the function a String containing the telephone number

`String number = "1234567890";
sms.SendSMS(number,"Text message");`

I get the following error:

`exit status 1 
no matching function for call to 'SMSGSM::SendSMS(String&, const char [27]);'`

I don't understand what String followed by an ampersand means. What am I supposed to pass the function as its first argument?

Comment: are you sure it is not the `sms.SendSMS("1234567890","Text message");` giving you "no matching function"?

Comment: @Juraj Yes I am sure. The `sms.SendSMS("1234567890","Text message"); ` works fine and the SMS is sent without any problem.

Comment: Hint: Try `sms.SendSMS(String("1234567890"),"Text message");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function prototype in [sms.h](https://github.com/fffaraz/gpst/blob/master/gsm-shield-arduino/branches/SIM908IDE100/sms.h) is

```
char SendSMS(char *number_str, char *message_str);
```

if `number` is `String`, you should have

```
sms.SendSMS((char*) number.c_str(),"Text message");
```

`c_str()` is a function of the Strinng class. It returns a pointer to internal char array of the String object.

The cast to `char*` is necessary because the author of the library didn't make the parameter constant with `const char*`. (It is a good practice, to declare pointers and references as constants.)

The error message `no matching function for call to 'SMSGSM::SendSMS(String&, const char [27]);` shows the arguments you try to use. `String&` is reference to some instance of the `String` type

Comment: if I use `sms.SendSMS(number.c_str(),"Text message");`    I get the error: `no matching function for call to 'SendSMS(const char*, const char [13])'`

Comment: `sms.SendSMS((char*) number.c_str(),"Text message");`

Comment: thank you very much, it works now. I still don't fully understand how `(char*)` works, would you mind to briefly explain it? thanks again

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm